# Using android phone as router to use RasPi by RDPDesk

Tags: raspbian, windows, android, rdp

I've set up my Pi to work on my home router, so that I can access it headlessly by using RDPDesk on my laptop.

I've done this by entering the ssid and key of the network in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. It works a treat on a number of networks.

However, I want to be able to use the Pi like this at University, where I'm unlikely to be allowed to use their servers, so I was hoping to use the SSID and PSK of my Android phone (Galaxy S4) whilst in tethering mode. When I enter these into the wpa supplicant file though, RDPDesk will not connect. Is there any way this is possible or is the phone not up to the job?

I am running up to date Rasbpian on a Model B, Windows 7 on the laptop and Jelly Bean on the S4.

Comment: It should work. Are you using the IP address of the Pi when you're using the Phone as an AP ?

Comment: The IP address on the Pi is static and then on the laptop RDPDesk has that IP saved.

Comment: That's likely your issue then. Unless your phone AP uses the same IP address range as your home network, the Pi will not have the correct IP to talk to anything else on the phone WiFi AP. You need to change the Pi's address to one that is on the Phones AP Range.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that I never had this answered. Turns out it's pretty simple. Just need to connect Android to USB, enable USB Tethering in Android (Settings --> More Networks --> Tethering and Postable Hotspot --> USB Tethering).

Then, on the pi:

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Add the following line at the bottom:

`iface usb0 inet dhcp`

Save and exit, then:

`sudo ifup usb0`

Reboot and (hopefully) voila!

This can be also set as static by instead of `iface usb0 inet dhcp` we add

`allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.yyy.yyy`

where address, netmask and broadcast are got from running 
`ifconfig` 
after setting up usb0 as above for DHCP :)